# what is a good way of understanding reg expression other people wrote

Tags: regex

I am asked to fix a line of regular expression someone else wrote. The expression is used to check for url matching. Is is extremely long, over 100 characters and are not well documented. Is there any tricks or short cut how how to tackle problems like this?

It looks like this:

```
/^(([\w]+:)?\/\/)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(\/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?$/
```

Comment: In Perl, you could convert the regex to the `x` format which allows whitespace and comments.

Comment: Wow, this is tough. I would put it in http://regexpal.com/ to get colored, then take paper and pencil, and start reading it piece by piece...

Comment: Throw it away and rewrite it yourself (assuming that you know your regex). When you rewrite, refer to the specs of URL.

Comment: Note that all `A-f` in there should probably be `A-F`

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what is wrong with the regex that needs fixing.

Comment: Get rid of that thing and create a custom method that does this check. Preferably using a built-in API that can validate URLs/URIs.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this using [YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.cpan.org/~gsullivan/YAPE-Regex-Explain-4.01/Explain.pm):

```
perl -MYAPE::Regex::Explain -e '
    my $regex = "/^...$/";
    print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new($regex)->explain;
'
```

### Sample Output

```
The regular expression:



matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2 (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(...)
```

See this post too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772594/regular-expression-explained-with-words

Comment: This only explains the syntax. Personally, I find such explanation makes no sense. It is easier to understand to reflect the regex back to the specification of whatever it is matching against and pick out the portions that matches some meaningful token.

Comment: @nhahtdh, no, `Regex::Explain` does not just explain syntax. For example, it groups the following into one "explanation-token": `[a-fA-f\d]{2,2}`. But yeah, such a large monster does not produce a very clear explanation... :)

Comment: It's a great start, and a framework for filling in your own notes on what it all means. Also helps if you are trying to quickly zero-in on a specific issue rather than absorb the whole thing at once.

Answer (score 2):

Break it up into multiple lines, and figure it out piece by piece.  If you don't know how to do this, you need to learn more of the regex syntax to understand how groups, repetition, alternation, and character classes work.

There are some websites that can help you see what these pieces are, for example you can mouse over the regex you enter on http://regexr.com and see just that piece highlighted and described, or put it into http://regexpal.com and get the entire regex highlighted in different colors.

Here is how I would break your regex down into more manageable chunks:

```
^
(
  ([\w]+:)?
  \/\/
)?
(
  (
    [\d\w]
    |
    %[a-fA-f\d]{2,2}
  )+
  (
    :
    (
      [\d\w]
      |
      %[a-fA-f\d]{2,2}
    )+
  )?
  @
)?
(
  [\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.
)+
[\w]{2,4}
(:[\d]+)?
(
  \/
  (
    [-+_~.\d\w]
    |
    %[a-fA-f\d]{2,2}
  )*
)*
(
  \?
  (
    &?
    (
      [-+_~.\d\w]
      |
      %[a-fA-f\d]{2,2}
    )
    =?
  )*
)?
(
  #
  (
    [-+_~.\d\w]
    |
    %[a-fA-f\d]{2,2}
  )*
)?
$
```

I am not going to take the time to actually work through what all of those pieces mean, but it looks to me like it is for validating URLs.

Comment: up-voted cause you provided me with something that is easier on the eye to work through and the first to do so :)

Answer (score 2):

1. **Know the regex syntax.**

   sputnick's answer shows one way to learn the meaning of the syntax. There are also plenty of regex testing websites that breaks down the regex and explain the meaning of the tokens.

   You can also refer to tutorials, or the documentation for regex in the language you are working with for more information. (It is important to read the documentation for the right language, since there are slight differences here and there in the regex implementation between languages).
2. **Gather context/domain knowledge.**

   Look for the reason that the regex is written, or what is the regex is intended to be used for. This is usually reflected in the comment, or the function name. For example, if the regex is used to clean the input before putting into `eval` function, then you may think of some attack vectors and check whether the regex does something to neutralize your attack.

   In your case, it is matching URL, so you can look up on Wikipedia and refer to the RFCs related to URL, and look for the BNF grammar. That is the best case, but even without that, you may already expect `/` or `?` or `#` appearing in the regex.
3. **Divide and conquer**

   You need to convert the regex to its "RAW" form. For example, if the regex is specified in a string, then you need to do extra escaping on some special character. You will reverse that process in the first step. In your case, the regex you have uses `/` as delimiter, so you need to undo the escaping done on `/`.

   ```
   ^(([\w]+:)?//)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?$
   ```

   Break the regex into big fragments, based on your domain knowledge, and also regex syntax:

   ```
   ^
   (([\w]+:)?//)?
   (([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+
   (:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?
   ([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}
   (:[\d]+)?
   (/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*
   (\?(&?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?
   (#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?
   $
   ```

   It is possible to guess the parts starting with `?` and `#` are query and fragment respectively. You can also guess that single `/` can only belong to path. You can also guess the part with `:` and `//` close to each other is most likely scheme. And `@` indicates something to do with username and password portion. You can reach at least half of what I have above with the guesses above.

   Another heuristic is to break the regex into "top-level" tokens ("top-level" in the abstract syntax tree). Usually, a single or a combination of a few "top-level" tokens correspond to some meaningful part in the text being matched.

   As you have broken the regex down into big fragments, if you have clear mapping of the regex fragments to the corresponding part of text you are trying to match, you can work on each of the fragments *independently*.

Comment: thanks that was really helpful to go through all those characters

Answer (score 0):

Feed it to a visualization tool.  Something like [Regexper](http://www.regexper.com/) will give you a view as to what is going on.

In this case, it looks like you have a regex for parsing a URI.  Given that, you are generally far better off feeding your input string to a URI parser and letting it do the hard work instead.  You obtain all the benefits and also are able to manipulate the object piece-by-piece.

Answer (score 0):

You can visualize it with [debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%5E%28%28%5B%5Cw%5D%2b%3a%29?%5C/%5C/%29?%28%28%5B%5Cd%5Cw%5D%7C%25%5Ba-fA-f%5Cd%5D%7B2,2%7D%29%2b%28%3a%28%5B%5Cd%5Cw%5D%7C%25%5Ba-fA-f%5Cd%5D%7B2,2%7D%29%2b%29?@%29?%28%5B%5Cd%5Cw%5D%5B-%5Cd%5Cw%5D%7B0,253%7D%5B%5Cd%5Cw%5D%5C.%29%2b%5B%5Cw%5D%7B2,4%7D%28%3a%5B%5Cd%5D%2b%29?%28%5C/%28%5B-%2b_~.%5Cd%5Cw%5D%7C%25%5Ba-fA-f%5Cd%5D%7B2,2%7D%29%2a%29%2a%28%5C?%28&?%28%5B-%2b_~.%5Cd%5Cw%5D%7C%25%5Ba-fA-f%5Cd%5D%7B2,2%7D%29=?%29%2a%29?%28#%28%5B-%2b_~.%5Cd%5Cw%5D%7C%25%5Ba-fA-f%5Cd%5D%7B2,2%7D%29%2a%29?%24&str=). It will show you a railroad diagram and give you sample matches that you can walk through step-by-step to see exactly what's happening inside your regex.